# Conectar una base de datos remota en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con *Laravel 5.2* y debo conectar una base de datos remota, para hacerlo desde la línea de comando tecleo.

```
mysql -u root -p -h 'remote_ip' --skip-secure-auth
```

Al hacer esto no manda ningún error, esto lo quiero hacer desde *Laravel*. ¿Cómo puedo agregar la opción?

> --skip-secure-auth
>   desde config/database.php

```
'estudiantesdb' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'remote_ip',
    'port' => '3306',
    'database' => 'estudiantesdb',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root_password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Answer (score 1):

**No** es posible hacer esto en Laravel, realmente la limitación no es de Laravel sino de PHP.

Entre los distintos parámetros que reciben los arrays de conexión de Laravel no permiten enviar algo así.

---

Además no es recomendado hacerlo según la documentación de MySQL 5.7.x :

> **--secure-auth**
>
> Do not send passwords to the server in old (pre-4.1) format. This prevents connections except for servers that use the newer password format.
>
> As of MySQL 5.7.5, this option is deprecated and will be removed in a future MySQL release. **It is always enabled and attempting to disable it (--skip-secure-auth, --secure-auth=0) produces an error.** Before MySQL 5.7.5, this option is enabled by default but can be disabled.

Comment: Que buena respuesta :o